# set_value in codeigniter not responding

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am new to the codeigniter and i am trying its tutorials from the user guide. But i just got stuck in one place. In the code of the form validations. I am trying its example for the set_value property but my user text box is not returning anything.

In my view i added the following code:

```
<?php echo validation_errors();?>
<?php echo form_open('form');?>
<table border="0">
<tr>
    <td><h5>Username</h5></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><h5>Password</h5></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" value="" size="50" accept=" <?php echo set_value('password'); ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><h5>password Confirm</h5></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="passconf" value="" size="50"  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><h5>Email Addres</h5></td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="email" value="" size="50" accept="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and in my controller i added the following code:

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','username','required|min_length[5]|max-length[10]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','password','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf','password confirmation','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('myform');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('formsucces');
    }
}
```

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two value attributes in your input type..

Try this...

```
<td><input type="text" name="username" size="50" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" /></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with CI and form validation...

You need own helper where grabs a value from the POST array for the specified field so you can re-populate an input field or textarea. If form validation is active it retrieves the info from the validation class

```
if (!function_exists('set_value')) {
    function set_value($field = '', $default = '') {
            $OBJ = & _get_validation_object();

            if ($OBJ === TRUE && isset($OBJ->_field_data[$field])) {
                    return form_prep($OBJ->set_value($field, $default));
            } else {
                    if (!isset($_POST[$field])) {
                            return $default;
                    }
                    return form_prep($_POST[$field]);
            }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This solution is working, best answer. By the way, what is the difference between

```
<?php echo set_value('field_name'); ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo @$_POST['field_name']; ?>
```